# How to take statistics from a website and make it into a DataFrame on python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a DataFrame from this website: http://mcubed.net/ncaab/seeds.shtml

I'm trying to make these lists into a DataFrame and to see the history of each seed in the NCAA tournament.
I'm not familiar with web-scraping and manually entering it would take awhile.
So I'm wondering if there is an easier way to create this DataFrame than manually doing it?

I've tried testing it with making my own dataframe and would manually input data from the website but it is a very long process

```
import pandas as pd
data= {"History of 1 Seed":["1 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 2 Seed":["2 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 3 Seed":["3 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 4 Seed":["4 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 5 Seed":["5 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 6 Seed":["6 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 7 Seed":["7 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 8 Seed":["8 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 9 Seed":["9 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 10 Seed":["10 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 11 Seed":["11 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 12 Seed":["12 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 13 Seed":["13 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 14 Seed":["14 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 15 Seed":["16 seed versus 1 seed"],
       "History of 16 Seed":["16 seed versus 1 seed"]
  
      }
df1= pd.DataFrame(data)
df1
```

I create my dataframe but I'm not sure how to input values into it and hoping there is an easier way to do this. Thanks

Comment: There are multiple tables on the website, which one do you want?

Comment: You can use `pd.read_html(url)` to generate a list of all tables on a page as dataframes, then go through that list to find the table(s) you want

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing the Website**

First step is to parse the website, and put the information into a DataFrame or a series of DataFrames. Here we use a combo of `requests` to get the text and `BeautifulSoup` to parse the html. The difficult aspect of your specific website it that the tables are just text, not specific html elements. So we have to go about this slightly differently than we would normally.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import StringIO

url = 'http://mcubed.net/ncaab/seeds.shtml'

#Getting the website text
data = requests.get(url).text

#Parsing the website
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")

#Create an empty list
dflist = []

#If we look at the html, we don't want the tag b, but whats next to it
#StringIO(b.next.next), takes the correct text and makes it readable to pandas
for b in soup.findAll({"b"})[2:-1]:
    dflist.append(pd.read_csv(StringIO(b.next.next), sep = r'\s+', header = None))

dflist[0]

     0   1     2      3
0   vs. #1  (23-23) 50.0%
1   vs. #2  (40-35) 53.3%
2   vs. #3  (25-15) 62.5%
```

**Cleaning, and Combining the DataFrames**

Next what we need to do is format all the dataframes in the list. I've also decided that we will combine all the dataframes, making team name a column, and who they are VS in another column. This will allow for easy filtering to get whatever information we need.

```
#We need to create a new list, due to the melt we are going to do not been able to replace
#the dataframes in DFList
meltedDF = []

#The second item in the loop is the team number starting from 1
for df, teamnumber in zip(dflist, (np.arange(len(dflist))+1)):

    #Creating the team name
    name = "Team " + str(teamnumber)

    #Making the team name a column, with the values in df[0] and df[1] in our dataframes
    df[name] = df[0] + df[1]

    #Melting the dataframe to make the team name its own column
    meltedDF.append(df.melt(id_vars = [0, 1, 2, 3]))

# Concat all the melted DataFrames
allTeamStats = pd.concat(meltedDF)

# Final cleaning of our new single DataFrame
allTeamStats = allTeamStats.rename(columns = {0:name, 2:'Record', 3:'Win Percent', 'variable':'Team' , 'value': 'VS'})\
                           .reindex(['Team', 'VS', 'Record', 'Win Percent'], axis = 1)

allTeamStats.head()

     Team    VS     Record  Win Percent
0   Team 1  vs.#1   (23-23) 50.0%
1   Team 1  vs.#2   (40-35) 53.3%
2   Team 1  vs.#3   (25-15) 62.5%
3   Team 1  vs.#4   (53-22) 70.7%
4   Team 1  vs.#5   (45-9)  83.3%
```

**Querying our new DF**

Now that we have all the information in a single DataFrame we can filter it to pull the information we want!

```
allTeamStats[allTeamStats['VS'] == 'vs.#1'].head()

     Team    VS     Record  Win Percent
0   Team 1  vs.#1   (23-23)   50.0%
0   Team 2  vs.#1   (35-40)   46.7%
0   Team 3  vs.#1   (15-25)   37.5%
0   Team 4  vs.#1   (22-53)   29.3%
0   Team 5  vs.#1   (9-45)    16.7%
```

If you wanted an easier way to investigate the wins and losses of a team, we could further create two new columns with their wins and losses separate from Record.

```
allTeamStats['Win'] = allTeamStats['Record'].str.extract(r'\((\d+)')
allTeamStats['Lose'] = allTeamStats['Record'].str.extract(r'\(\d+-(\d+)')

allTeamStats.head()

     Team    VS     Record  Win Percent Win Lose
0   Team 1  vs.#1   (23-23)   50.0%     23  23
1   Team 1  vs.#2   (40-35)   53.3%     40  35
2   Team 1  vs.#3   (25-15)   62.5%     25  15
3   Team 1  vs.#4   (53-22)   70.7%     53  22
4   Team 1  vs.#5   (45-9)    83.3%     45  9
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This is really helpful. I'm trying to tinker with your code and was wondering if there is a way to show all 16 teams and not just the 5 teams that pop up?  I'm referring to the code:  allTeamStats[allTeamStats['VS'] == 'vs.#1'].head() Thanks again